# Dynamic variable in Auth Headers - Azure Data Factory

Tags: odata, azure-data-factory

I have a ADF flow where I first retrieve an Oauth 2.0 token which then should be used in an Odata request.
This works perfect if I first extract the token and then hard code it in the auth headers(Bearer xxxxxxxx).

However I want to use a variable which I set earlier in the flow in this value. Like "Bearer [variable]". I have tried with the following: "Bearer @variables('Token')" but it doesnt work. I have double checked and the variable 'Token' is getting the correct token value so this should not be the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0Q4c.png)

So my question is whether it is possible to use variables in the Auth Header section?

I have tried to use "Bearer @variables('Token')" in the Value field for Auth Headers. This doesnt work unfortunately.

Comment: you might have to use @concat('Bearer ', variables('Token')) , make sure you have the space after Bearer.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger When I use that as Auth Header Value I get this error:

ErrorCode=ODataFailedClientCreation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to create odata connection to RequestUrl.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.ODataConnector,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=The format of value '@concat('Bearer ', variables('Token'))' is invalid.,Source=System.Net.Http

Comment: It seems that the ADF doesnt like dynamic content in the Auth Header value

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the Linked Service itself?  I am assuming because that is the only image you show.  It needs to be a parameter in the Linked Service that is set when you use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I reproduced the same thing in my environment and got this output***

- *Create a web activity and generated a bearer token with a sample URL* and *Create a parameter  variable with the name `Token`*

[image]

- *Create a set variable and use this dynamic content value `@activity('Web1').output.data.Token`*

[image]

*Then, I created a copy activity with **`Additional headers`**.

As suggested by @**Scott Mildenberger***

```
Authorization: @concat('Bearer ', variables('token'))
```

[image]

> ***Pipeline successfully executed and got the output:***

[image]

[image]