# Azure Data Factory difference in value between hardcoded and dynamic values?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have a web activity in Azure Data Factory that works like a dream when I hardcode the values into the headers.  One specific header for Authorization SHOULD be using the @activity('CallFunctionApp').output.Response value, which is dynamic but I receive an invalid response from the API.  When the value is hardcoded with the same value as the activity output.Response the API gives a fully and complete response.  I have String()'d the value, but this makes no difference.

Is there something I am missing or can anyone help please?

This is trying to hit the Mimecast API (if anyone has any experience with this)

I have compared the outgoing JSON response for both activities (working and not working) and they are IDENTICAL, space for space.  So, it is clear there is something behind that I am unaware of.

An example of the outgoing JSON :

```
{
    "url": "https://au-api.mimecast.com/api/account/get-account",
    "connectVia": {
        "referenceName": "IR-AzureHosted",
        "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
    },
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "MC mYtOL3p-4IQ:q7iVKTtxsylqTRn20oEvuhGdJxk=",
        "x-mc-date": "Tue, 06 Jun 2023 02:44:48 GMT",
        "x-mc-req-id": "B007nvonvonvonvnvownvowrnvoiw-1883EA87D803",
        "x-mc-app-id": "76jrgvwrvwrvwroivrnmrwpivwvwirvwrpi97c3d9b",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "data": []
    }
}
```

I have tried to string() the Authorization
[image: pipeline image]

in this image, some of the values are sent to the function app, and the Authorization value is returned from the functionapp , "MC blahblahblah", and this value, along with the rest of the headers are all sent to the GetJSONWebSource.  The SetVariable for Authorization is using @activity('CallFunctionApp').output.Response, hopefully that makes sense.  The FunctionApp is SHA1 AND Base64 encoding variables to generate the "MC blahblahblah" value, which in turn is sent as the Authorization header.  The rest of the headers are there to help the receiving API to decode the Authorization and allow a response.

[image: function app output]

Functionapp output image added, maybe the 'charset=utf-8' is causing the issue?

Comment: I have set the value to a variable and referenced that, and get the same outcome.

Comment: I have also got the Authorization value from a lookup and referenced that and got the same outcome.

Comment: can you please add images which header value you are getting from function ad youa re referring it in web activity?

Comment: can you please add output of 'CallFunctionApp' activity image?

Comment: @PratikLad - thankyou, have added the functionapp output, could the charset=utf-8 be causing the issue do you think?  thanks for your help.

Comment: @PratikLad - thankyou for your valuable help, please see my resolution to this. I am elated!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I have modified the functionapp to return everything AFTER the "MC " and then concat the "MC " onto the start of the return ready for the header.  I expect that the " " was causing the issue after all.

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is correct still not able to get the reason for error causing may be because the type of the response in not what header is accepting or its not fetching proper value from function response.

**The workaround:**

- You can try by creating set variable and the store the value of function response in it as a string and
  [image]
- Then refer this variable in web activity header.
  [image]

Refer this similar [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74527789)

Comment: Thankyou @Pratik Lad , unfortunately this returns the same result.  Frustratingly! Still fails with a 'the format of value 'xxxxx' is invalid' error message.  Thankyou, any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user3735855 can you please add output of 'CallFunctionApp' activity image?